# Running Wordcount with Hadoop streaming, using Python code

Tags: java, python, hadoop

I am using Cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.2 and trying to execute the following map-reduce command:

`hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -input /user/cloudera/input -output /user/cloudera/output_new -mapper /home/cloudera/wordcount_mapper.py -reducer /home/cloudera/wordcount_reducer.py`

It returns with lots of exceptions in the logs similar to these:

[image: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object]

[image: Streaming Command Failed!]

I do not understand how to fix the exceptions that appear in the log.

I have verified the contents of the input directory

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls 
Found 6 items 
drwxr-xr-x - cloudera cloudera 0 2016-02-14 13:59 input
drwxr-xr-x - cloudera cloudera 0 2016-02-14 11:05 output
drwxr-xr-x - cloudera cloudera 0 2016-02-14 14:13 output_new
-rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera 2561 2016-02-04 20:17 passwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera 1073741824 2016-02-13 15:27 sample.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera 20 2016-01-18 19:58 testfile.txt
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your input **directory** exist on HDFS? I see a no such file exception

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes, I've just checked hdfs dfs -ls and the input file is there. [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls
Found 6 items
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2016-02-14 13:59 input
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2016-02-14 11:05 output
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2016-02-14 14:13 output_new
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera       2561 2016-02-04 20:17 passwd
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera 1073741824 2016-02-13 15:27 sample.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera         20 2016-01-18 19:58 testfile.txt
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$

Comment: I guess the problem is becuase of SetJobConf method. Can you update your question with your piece of codes?

Comment: Hi Mobin, I am trying to run a program with hadoop streaming using Python code. The code for the mapper program is #!/user/bin/env python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin :
        line = line.strip()
        keys = line.split()
        for key in keys :
                value = 1
                print ('{0}\t{1}'.format(key, value))

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code. The problem is Hadoop is not recognizing the the file in /home/python_mapper.py. It could be the PATH in CDH that not setup properly. Just my thoughts. When I type "Python" in the command line, I see Python 2.6 is installed but when I try to run "python wordcount_mapper.py" the command line gets stuck and doesn't move at all.

Comment: I have just figured out that both mapper.py and reducer.py files should be sitting on HDFS and now it's working. I was trying to execute those from /home which was wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.13.0.jar -file /home/cloudera/Desktop/mapper.py  -mapper /home/cloudera/Desktop/mapper.py -file /home/cloudera/Desktop/reducer.py -reducer /home/cloudera/Desktop/reducer.py  -input /wordcount/wc.txt -output /wordcount/output4

Please try to use the command in cloudera VM. Its worked for me.